# Live Kali Linux root/toor login not working

Tags: kali-linux, login, password

Today I tried to get Live Kali Linux working off a USB stick. When I got to the login screen, I tried entering `root` as the username and `toor` as the password like always, but the login failed. I am out of ideas, since the official Kali site still says those should be the correct login credentials.

Here are the steps for reproducing on my Lenovo y700 laptop:

1. Download a Kali linux iso image from the [official website](https://www.kali.org/downloads/). I tried 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the latest Kali Linux and I also tried an old 2018 image, all with the same results
2. Burn the image onto a flash drive. For this I tried using Rufus, Etcher and the `dd` tool from Linux. I followed the instructions on the official website.
3. Plug the USB into the computer, choose "Legacy Mode" from BIOS boot screen (because if I choose UEFI, then even if USB boot is enabled, it says usb boot is disabled in uefi settings). When the grub screen comes up, I can choose either kali or "advanced options". There is no option for installation.
4. Choose the live version and it will boot into a login screen. Enter `root` as the username and `toor` as the password, and get `invalid credentials` as the response

Comment: 1. Are you sure you downloaded the correct image from the correct website?
2. Did you check the hash to verify the integrity of the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don’t know if you still need this, but to anyone who does, Kali changed the password structure from root/toor to kali/kali. This was driving me crazy as it was always root/toor before.

See: https://www.kali.org/news/kali-default-non-root-user/

Answer (score 0):

Username: Kali 
Password: Kali

read more here https://www.kali.org/news/kali-default-non-root-user/